# Kernel panics if console=tty0 is not in kernel command line

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel

I configured my Ubuntu 18.04 system to use an early boot console, changing the kernel command line arguments to:

```
console=uart,mmio32,0xd091c000 console=tty0
```

This gives me an early boot console over a serial port until a certain point during boot, then switches over to sending kernel logs to `/dev/tty0`, and then the system comes up just fine.

Since I want *all* kernel logs to come across my serial port, I removed `console=tty0`.

```
console=uart,mmio32,0xd091c000
```

The problem now is that there is a kernel panic:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
```

There is nothing in the log that seems to indicate an error.

What would this command line argument be required to boot?

Comment: I thought that if you wanted the serial console completely it would be `console=ttyS0` where the `S0` is the first serial port, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my theory. The UART-based console is not a real TTY. The *intention* is for the kernel to switch to a regular serial device later, according to the docs for the `console=` option (emphasis added):

> Start an early, polled-mode console on the 8250/16550 UART at the specified I/O port or MMIO address, **switching to the matching ttyS device later**.

However, this hasn't happened at the time that `/init` starts:

```
[    3.329451] Run /init as init process
```

The device name is assigned much later:

```
[    6.759113] 0000:00:1e.3: ttyS4 at MMIO 0xd091c000 (irq = 18, base_baud = 2764800) is a 16550A
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like `console=ttyS4` to match above should fix it.

Comment: The problem is that I'm skeptical that ttyS4 is a stable name, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/637069/stabilizing-serial-device-names-across-reboots-for-serial-console/637077

Comment: The only acceptable `console=` parameters are `tty` and `lp`:  https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/configure-kernel.html  We use this line all the time in the Data Centers for controlling the host through the BMC / iDRAC / IPMI.  Direct serial works like this as well by setting the `ttyS#`, but if a host gets hung a direct serial does not have the ability to power cycle / power reset a server like the BMC / iDRAC hardware does.